# Labyrinth Problem in Python while iteration

Tags: python

```
map=  [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
      [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
      [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
      [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
      [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

class Runner:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def trans_loc(self, way):
        if way =='left':
            self.x += 1
        elif way =='right':
            self.x -= 1
        elif way =='up':
            self.y += 1
        elif way =='down':
            self.y -= 1
        pass
    def get_location(self): 
        return (self.x, self.y)

class Labyrinth:
    def __init__(self, map=None):
        self.map = map
        self.player = Runner()
        self.road = []

    def running(self): # Problem is Here
        x,y = self.player.get_location()
        self.road.append((x,y))
        lim = len(map)-1
    
        while lim:
            x += 1
            y += 1
            self.road.append((x,y))
            
            if x == lim and y == lim:
                break

    def given_map(self):
        return self.map

    def path_find(self):
        return self.road

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    trial = Labyrinth(map)
    trial.running()
    print(trial.given_map())
    print(trial.path_find())
```

To be honest, the code is part of myschool project. After a long time of googling and contemplation, I was only able to complete it up to here.The operation method of the code was designed as follows.Get a list of maps of the Labyrinth. Then return only the part with zero and add it to the self.road.
My problem is that I don't know how to weave the **running()** function part and the **trans_loc()** part. I know this site is not originally posting questions for this purpose, but I can't stand it because I'm so pathetic myself. It's okay to say something bitter, so I'd really appreciate it if you could give me a indirect solution.

Comment: How would you know when you are in the goal?

Comment: should the player be all the way in the right side just?

Comment: q:should the player be all the way in the right side just?
a:I don't think it matters.

Comment: q: How would you know when you are in the goal? a: It was a bit crude and cumbersome process, but I solved it by directly comparing the indexes of map list and the returned tuple list self.road one by one.

Comment: You can use recursion to do it :)

Comment: Sir, Can you attach some examples?
I've tried that method, but I'm quite confused about which function to specify.

Comment: Yes Ill give you an example in a bit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the coordinates for all the places in the matrix with the value 0 then you can do it like this:

```
lab =   [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

zeros = [(x,y) for y,l in enumerate(lab) for x,e in enumerate(l) if e == 0]
print(zeros)
```

If you want the shortest path you can use recursion like this

```
def getv(x, l): return x if x in range(len(l)) else -1
def move(x, y, lab):
    # Set current place to 1 to avoid going back
    lab[y][x] = 1 
    # Check if we are in the goal
    if x == len(lab[y])-1: return [(x,y)]
    # Check if we are out of bounds 
    if x < 0 or y < 0: return None

    up = right = left = down = None

    # Recursively check all paths
    if lab[getv(y+1,lab)][x]    == 0: down    = move(x,y+1, lab)
    if lab[getv(y-1,lab)][x]    == 0: up      = move(x,y-1, lab)
    if lab[y][getv(x+1,lab[y])] == 0: left    = move(x+1,y, lab)
    if lab[y][getv(x-1,lab[y])] == 0: right   = move(x-1,y, lab)

    # Only return coordinates of valid paths
    if   up:    return [(x,y)] + up
    elif down:  return [(x,y)] + down
    elif left:  return [(x,y)] + left
    elif right: return [(x,y)] + right 

def draw(path, lab):
    for x,y in path: lab[y][x] = '+'
    for x in lab: print(' '.join(str(x) for x in x))

# Find the path on the lab

path = move(0,0, 
        [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])


# path is [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 4), (5, 4)]


# Draw the path on the lab

draw(path,
        [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Prints

```
+ 1 1 1 1 1
+ + 1 0 0 1
1 + + + 0 1
1 0 1 + 1 1
1 0 1 + + +
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer by spending your time.
To improve my coding skills, I will analyze it for as long as possible.
If I still can't solve it in 24hours, can you tell me the answer?

Comment: The answer is in the path, however it will change with the labyrinth